# Pass Different Values for a function parameter in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a forecasting function hw() in R with below parameters:
`hw(TS, initial = 'simple', alpha = a,beta= b ,gamma=g,h=future_num)`
where alpha, beta, and gamma vary from 0 to 1 with an increment of 0.1.

I want to run this function for all the combination of alpha, beta, and gamma on one go and so have written below code:

```
  volume = 'UpdatedVol1'
  TS <- ts(Data_summary[volume],start = c(sy,sm),frequency = freq) 
  model_out = data.frame()
  for(i in 1:length(alpha)){
    for(j in 1:length(beta)){
       for(k in 1:length(gama)){
          ### Model Output ###
          #alpha = 0.2
          fore_hw <- hw(TS, initial = 'simple', alpha = 
                     alpha[i],beta=beta[j],gamma=gama[k],h=future_num)
          hw <- data.frame(ForecastVol =as.numeric(round(fore_hw$mean)))
          hw$ModelName <- "Ex HW"
          hw$Alpha <- alpha[i]
          hw$Beta <- beta[j]
          hw$Gama <- gama[k]
          model_out <- rbind(model_out,hw)    
       }
     }
   }
```

where Data_summary is data frame with 150 rows, freq = 7 and future_num = 300

Is there any possibility to run the hw() function with all alpha, beta, and gamma values at once? or any option to optimise this code as it is taking more than 8 mins to run this code

Comment: You're `rbind`ing within each iteration of the loop.  That's inefficient.  So an obvious improvement would be to `rbind` (or `dplyr::bind_rows()`) only once, at the end of the loops.  One way to do this would be to use (nested) `lapply`s instead of `for` loops.  `lapply` returns a list, which can conveniently be passed directly to `bind_rows`.  But if `TS` is large and `hw()` performs a complex analysis, you're always going to wait a while.

Answer (score 1):

`rbind()` inside a loop is notoriously inefficient. See [The Second Circle of R Hell in the R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for a detailed explanation.

A quick fix is to put all the model results in a `list` and then use `rbind` once at the end:

```
# create a list and counter
results <- list()
counter <- 1

volume = 'UpdatedVol1'
  TS <- ts(Data_summary[volume],start = c(sy,sm),frequency = freq) 
  model_out = data.frame() ## this seems to be unused??
  for(i in 1:length(alpha)){
    for(j in 1:length(beta)){
       for(k in 1:length(gama)){
          ### Model Output ###
          #alpha = 0.2
          fore_hw <- hw(TS, initial = 'simple', alpha = 
                     alpha[i],beta=beta[j],gamma=gama[k],h=future_num)
          hw <- data.frame(ForecastVol =as.numeric(round(fore_hw$mean)))
          hw$ModelName <- "Ex HW"
          hw$Alpha <- alpha[i]
          hw$Beta <- beta[j]
          hw$Gama <- gama[k]
          # add to the list and increment the counter
          results[[counter]] <- hw
          counter <- counter + 1
       }
     }
   }
   results <- do.call(rbind, results) # one rbind at the end
   # (you can use `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist` to do this faster)
```

You could certainly do better than this too, but this will be a vast improvement with minimal changes.

Comment: ... or do it this way for minimal changes to your code!

Comment: This really helped reduce the run time! Thank you @Gregor Thomas